# Passing two variables from function

Tags: javascript, return

I'm trying to accomplish three functions, where one gets two values from HTML-elements, one counts exponent of these values and one console.logs what the values used were and the result.

What way would function noudaArvo be able to pass both variables to other functions? I'm trying not to change other two functions.

```
function laskuFunktio() { //does the printing
    var luku = noudaArvo("luku");
    var eksp = noudaArvo("eksponentti");

    console.log("Luku " + luku + " potenssiin " + eksp + " on:");
    console.log(laskePotenssi(luku, eksp));
}

function noudaArvo() { //gets the values, but can't figure how to pass them out
    let luku = document.getElementById("luku").value;
    let eksponentti = document.getElementById("eksponentti").value;
}

function laskePotenssi() { //counts the exponent
    var luku = noudaArvo("luku");
    var eksponentti = noudaArvo("eksponentti");
    return Math.pow(luku, eksponentti);
}
```

Comment: A function can return only one value, but that value can f.e. be an array or object.

Comment: Here however it would perhaps make more sense, if your function actually took that parameter you are already calling it with, and then simply returned one or the other, based on a simple if/else.

Comment: You can either return an array of the two values, or an object (something like `return {luku, eksponentti}`, and then you can access them like this `const {luku, eksponentti} = noudaArvo()`, and then you can use luku and eksponentti as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function laskuFunktio() { //does the printing
    var luku = noudaArvo("luku");
    var eksp = noudaArvo("eksponentti");

    console.log("Luku " + luku + " potenssiin " + eksp + " on:");
    console.log(laskePotenssi(luku, eksp));
}

function noudaArvo(item) { //gets the values, but can't figure how to pass them out
    return document.getElementById(item).value;
}

function laskePotenssi(luku, eksp) { //counts the exponent
    return Math.pow(luku, eksp);
}
```

If I understand what your saying correctly this may be a solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

U don't return from noudaArvo function anything
change the function to

```
function noudaArvo(elId) { //gets the values, but can't figure how to pass them out
    return document.getElementById(elId).value;
}
```